# Adding date and time to the same request

Tags: php, array

I would like to call the `get_the_date` and `get_the_time` in the same request. Is this possible? This what I'm doing now.

```php
<?php

$header = array(

      //Home
"15" => array(
        "article:published_date" =>get_the_date(''),
        "modified_time" =>get_the_time(''),
),)
?>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but what isn't working for you? Where are you running the code, is it being called via a hook (or function hooked on to a filter/action)?

Comment: I'm calling to a header for my meta tags, but like for it to show in one tag only like this: 2023-01-16T18:37:52+00:00

<meta property="article:published_time" content="<?=$header[get_queried_object_id()]['article:published_date']?>" /> 
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="<?=$header[get_queried_object_id()]['modified_date']?>" />

Comment: id prefer to call the dateModified from my schema if possible but don't know how to pull form a script or json-id

Comment: To allow better formatting of code samples, please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/412904/edit) to add more context or clarify things rather than trying to post code here in the comments.

Comment: @Richard note that `get_queried_object_id()` is meant to get the ID of the queried post/category/etc. on singular pages like a post page or category archive, and since your array keys are presumably the post ID, you should pass the post ID when calling `get_the_date()` and `get_the_time()`, e.g. `get_the_date( 'c', 15 )`. Additionally, make sure to check if an array key exists before attempting to get its value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get an ISO8601-formatted datetime, you can just use [`get_the_date()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/) as it'll actually return the date and time a post was published.

So something like `get_the_date( 'c' )` should get you the date and time, formatted how you want them (per your comment).

Comment: Thank you, what i was looking for

Comment: If an answer helps you out, you can mark it as "Accepted", which may help out other having the same problem you were having.